# Can I use AdSense and AdExchange enabled networks together on a website

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I run a website where I have 3 AdSense units and 2 ad units from another ad network.

The OTHER ad network sent me an DFP AdExchange invitation, saying that by signing up, they would be able to send more ads to my ad units and increase my revenue.

The invitation url looks like this

```
https://www.google.com/adxseller/participant-registration?invitation=[LONG CODE]
```

Is it okay to sign up for AdExchange when I am already using AdSense on my site.
Is there any official statement from Google about its policies on this topic ?

I did come across [this doc](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//adexchange/AdExchangeOverview.pdf) which explains how AdExchange works.

Comment: More than 3 units are going to contribute to ad blindness. Your ads will get fewer impressions, I'd say give it a try on a site with 1 or 2 units.

Answer (score 1):

This goes beyond Ad blindness. Google has recently updated their AdSense policy removing the 3 ad unit limit per page and instead assess the overall balance of ads to content, specifically citing infinite scroll pages as an example of where more than 3 ad units may be appropriate.

Based on your question it would depend on the amount of unique content you have on your page. Google recommends that you keep the user experience in mind and requires that you have more unique content than ad units.

Comment: I think you should edit your answer, since [Google adsense change it's policy regarding maximum 3 ad unit](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-adsense-drops-ad-limit-per-page-policy-22580.html)

Comment: The article you referenced @Goyllo seems to say that the page has just disappeared not that the policy has been retracted, and in the past when Google has changed limit policies etc they have prepended the page to say that the policy has been changed or removed. Until Google actually comes out and confirms that the ad limits have been changed to a higher amount or removed entirely I think I have to stick to my original answer.

Comment: [It is confirmed by one of Google employee](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-adsense-drops-ad-limit-per-page-policy-22580.html). They have not made any blog announcement, but we can clearly see the new ads policy page, and it does not have such a words that "don't place max 3 banner ads per page." For me it is official announcement.